List All Workdays between Start and End Dates Displaying Associated Name and Details in Other Columns
I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:



Entry Date
Start
End
Name
Details




9/13/2024 13:46:03
09/13/2024
09/13/2024
James Jameson
Out—Called off-Emergency


9/15/202413:46:45
09/30/2024
10/04/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


9/15/202413:43:53
09/16/2024
10/04/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


9/29/202413:44:49
09/30/2024
09/30/2024
Jacob Jacobson
Out—Called off-Sick



I would like to list out each WORKDAY beginning with Start Date and ending with End Date with the associated Name and Details for each date sorted by entry date.  This would be an ARRAYFORMULA since I am using a form to populate the entries in the spreadsheet.  This is what the result should look like (note that weekends are filtered out):



Date
Name
Details




09/13/2024
James Jameson
Out—Called off-Emergency


09/16/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/17/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/18/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/19/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/20/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/23/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/24/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/25/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/26/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/27/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/30/2024
William Williamson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


09/30/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/30/2024
Andrew Anderson
Out—Called off-Sick


10/01/2024
William Williamson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/01/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/02/2024
William Williamson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/02/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/03/2024
William Williamson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/03/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/04/2024
William Williamson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/04/2024
David Davidson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation



I tried to modify player0's formula in the accepted Stack Overflow answer here, but I kept getting errors.
Does anyone have a recommendation for going about this?
Thank you.

If the start & end  dates for Out—Called off-Sick are both Sunday 09/29, the output should have Monday 09/30 as one row?!

Sorry.  Nope.  If someone enters a start and end date on the same weekend day, it should not even display.  But I am not quite sure how that happened.  My spreadsheet shows 09/30/2024.  I must have realized the mistake and changed it on the spreadsheet after creating the table.

You can try:
=SORT(SPLIT(TOCOL(
  MAP(B2:B5,C2:C5,D2:D5,E2:E5,LAMBDA(s,e,n,d,LET(
     x,SEQUENCE(1,e-s+1,s),
     IFNA(FILTER(x,"S"<>LEFT(TEXT(x,"ddd")))&"❅"&n&"❅"&d)))),1),"❅"))


Try this:
=SORT(LET(
a, map(C2:C5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(c,b,DAYS(c,b)+1)),
d, TOCOL(map(a,D2:D5,LAMBDA(x,y,SPLIT(REPT(y&",",x),","))),1),
e, TOCOL(map(a,E2:E5,LAMBDA(x,y,SPLIT(REPT(y&",",x),","))),1),
f, TOCOL(MAP(a,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,TOROW(SEQUENCE(x,1,y)))),1),
g, BYROW(f, LAMBDA(h, WEEKDAY(h))),
i, HSTACK(f,d,e,g),
QUERY(i,"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col4 <> 1 AND Col4 <> 7")),
1,1)

Based on the input:



Entry Date
Start
End
Name
Details




9/13/2024 13:46:03
09/13/2024
09/13/2024
James Jameson
Out—Called off-Emergency


9/15/202413:46:45
09/30/2024
10/04/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


9/15/202413:43:53
09/16/2024
10/04/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


9/29/202413:44:49
09/29/2024
09/29/2024
Jacob Jacobson
Out—Called off-Sick



Output:










09/13/2024
James Jameson
Out—Called off-Emergency


09/16/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/17/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/18/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/19/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/20/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/23/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/24/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/25/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/26/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/27/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


09/30/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


09/30/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/01/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/01/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/02/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/02/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/03/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/03/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation


10/04/2024
Jack Jackson
Out—Scheduled off-Paternity leave


10/04/2024
John Johnson
Out—Scheduled off-Vacation



References:

LET
MAP
DAYS
REPT
SEQUENCE
HSTACK
WEEKDAY


Please feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above.

Works well except this does not filter out the weekends.

Oh, I see. Let me edit the formula to disregard weekends

I have added an internal helper column and a query to filter out weekdays. Please check if it works on your end.

Works perfectly now.  Thanks.  I don't know that there is a better answer between the two, so I went with z.'s since it came in first.  Still gave you an upvote though.
